# Cannot create database, while having init script in AppConfig. django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my django application i have next code in `apps.py` file:

```
class NewsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_news'

    def ready(self):
        super().ready()
        from service.cache import cache
        cache.init_cache()
```

Purpose of `init_cache` method is to load data from database to redis cache. code:

```
def init_cache():
    from app_news.models import News
    for news in News.objects.all().order_by('-pk'):
        do_some_logic(news)
```

When I'm trying to create database with `manage.py migrate` command, I'm getting next error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_news_news`

As far as i understand, `migrate` loads all applications and calls `ready` method from `AppConfig`, so I cannot create database.

Maybe there is some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid doing queries in `ready` method, as it has been mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Maybe you can call your `init_cache` method somewhere else, like, `wsgi.py` or `urls.py` so does not get called by all management commands.

Comment: Thanks! But i dont think that cache initialization should be in `urls.py`. In my opinion - this is not obviously.